# Input file must be in csv format

Tags: contacts, import

I am trying to import a csv file as a test into Civicrm. I first exported the exact same file from Civicrm, and then i tried to import the exact same file. When i click on Continue, i get an error "Input file must be in CSV format". 
I have this error code:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Map1.csv
    [type] => 
    [tmp_name] => 
    [error] => 6
    [size] => 0
)
```

Can someone tell me what to do?

With kind regards,
Hilco Regterschot

Answer (score 2):

Your name sounds Dutch, what often happens to me is that if you open this file with Excel and save it again, it is saved with ; in stead of ,

Could that be the case?

It also is possible it is saved as an Excel file in stead of .csv

Comment: That's right, i am Dutch ;-).<br/>I have opened the file and saved it bak top csv. I also tried to copy and paste the data into a new csv file, with , as text separator. I also tried to create another file with the same data, but with text seperator ;. ,<br/>In Civicrm i changed Import Field Separator to ; and tried to import again. Same error.<br/>Both times i saved the file as CSV. Do you have other suggestions i can try?

Comment: please send me (part of) your .csv file

Comment: It is very possible that you have the wrong encoding. To be able to see that you have to send the CSV file, which is what @Catorghans already offered :-)

Comment: I have send the file to @Catorghans. There was nothing wrong with the file. I have asked my client if Catorghans can get access to the site and server, so he can take a look.